# Initializing numpy array from np.empty

Tags: python, numpy, heap-memory

How are the sign bits determined when initializing an ndarray from empty memory?

```
>>> np.random.randn(3,3)
array([[-0.35557367, -0.0561576 , -1.84722985],
       [ 0.89342124, -0.50871646,  1.31368413],
       [ 0.0062188 ,  1.62968789,  0.72367089]])
>>> np.empty((3,3))
array([[0.35557367, 0.0561576 , 1.84722985],
       [0.89342124, 0.50871646, 1.31368413],
       [0.0062188 , 1.62968789, 0.72367089]])
```

These float values initialized from empty memory have lost their signs<sup>†</sup>.  Why is that?

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Note: this result relies on implementation detail of memory re-use. The question asks what the implementation is doing.*</sub>

Comment: Can it be related to the fact that the last output is saved to the variable `_`? I see identical results when I print them.

Comment: This is (likely) the [entrypoint](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3034) for numpy.empty. I can't read C anymore, so god only knows what it's doing.

Comment: It can happen that sign information is kept independently for contiguous memory and thrown out for `empty`

Comment: On one hand, there's no way that `np.empty` call is reusing the `np.random.randn` return value's buffer. The `randn` array is still alive due to the `_` variable. On the other hand, I have no idea what could be causing the observed behavior. The [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1360) of `randn` doesn't seem to use scratch data that would look like that.

Comment: Looks like explicitly saving the `randn` return value changes how the `empty` result turns out in my trials, but explicitly saving the `empty` result has no effect.

Comment: Further experiment shows it's not anything to do with deallocating the `randn` return value; printing the `empty` return value before the `randn` return value is deallocated shows the same results.

Comment: I have a strong feeling `empty` is reusing the buffer of an array created in the process of *printing* the first array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy.empty` isn't clearing the sign bits manually or anything. The sign bits are just whatever garbage happens to be left in those bits of the `malloc` return value. The effect you're seeing is due to a `numpy.absolute` call somewhere else.

The thing is, `numpy.empty` isn't reusing the `randn` return value's buffer. After all, the `randn` return value is still alive when `empty` creates its array, due to the `_` variable.

`numpy.empty` is reusing the buffer of an array created in the process of *stringifying* the first array. I believe it's [this one](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.5/numpy/core/arrayprint.py#L804):

```
def fillFormat(self, data):
    # only the finite values are used to compute the number of digits
    finite_vals = data[isfinite(data)]

    # choose exponential mode based on the non-zero finite values:
    abs_non_zero = absolute(finite_vals[finite_vals != 0])
    ...
```

See that `absolute` call? That's the one.

Here's some additional testing that supports that conclusion:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.randn(3, 3)
>>> b = numpy.arange(-5, 4, dtype=float)
>>> c = numpy.arange(-5, 13, 2, dtype=float)
>>> a
array([[-0.96810932,  0.86091026, -0.32675013],
       [-1.23458136,  0.56151178, -0.37409982],
       [-1.71348979,  0.64170792, -0.20679512]])
>>> numpy.empty((3, 3))
array([[ 0.96810932,  0.86091026,  0.32675013],
       [ 1.23458136,  0.56151178,  0.37409982],
       [ 1.71348979,  0.64170792,  0.20679512]])
>>> b
array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
>>> numpy.empty((3, 3))
array([[ 0.96810932,  0.86091026,  0.32675013],
       [ 1.23458136,  0.56151178,  0.37409982],
       [ 1.71348979,  0.64170792,  0.20679512]])
>>> c
array([ -5.,  -3.,  -1.,   1.,   3.,   5.,   7.,   9.,  11.])
>>> numpy.empty((3, 3))
array([[  5.,   3.,   1.],
       [  1.,   3.,   5.],
       [  7.,   9.,  11.]])
>>> numpy.array([1.0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
array([ 1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> numpy.empty((3, 3))
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

The `numpy.empty` results are affected by printing `a` and `c`, rather than by the process of creating those arrays. `b` has no effect, because it has 8 nonzero elements. The final `array([1.0, 0, 2, ...])` has an effect, because even though it has 10 elements, exactly 9 of them are nonzero.

Comment: Good detective work, this seems promising, but using [`del builtins._`](https://gist.github.com/wimglenn/fb4e4c04c067d6d566f7f2ca023bdd2a) seems to suggest there might be more to it than just the `absolute` call from printing here.  Any ideas?

Comment: @wim: `del builtins._` causes that array to be deallocated, so `numpy.empty` ends up reusing that array's memory instead of the array created by `absolute`.

Comment: (Without `del builtins._`, the `randn` return value gets deallocated between the creation of the `numpy.empty` return value and the stringification of the `numpy.empty` return value, because `sys.displayhook` sets `builtins._` to `None` before stringifying or printing anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that NumPy is written in C (and some Fortran, C++), and the answer may be unrelated to Python, I'll try to use a few example to elucidate what's happening. The multi-language aspect makes this quite tricky, so you may need to inspect the implementation of the np.empty() function here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matlib.py#L13

Did you try:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.random.randn(3,3))
print(np.empty((3,3)))
```

I get output: (signs are preserved)

```
[[-1.13898052  0.99079467 -0.07773854]
 [ 1.18519122  1.30324795 -0.38748375]
 [-1.46435162  0.53163777  0.22004651]]
[[-1.13898052  0.99079467 -0.07773854]
 [ 1.18519122  1.30324795 -0.38748375]
 [-1.46435162  0.53163777  0.22004651]]
```

You'll notice the behavior changes based on two things:

1. whether you print or just output the value
2. how many empty arrays you create

For example, try running these two examples:

```
# Run this over and over and you'll always get different results!

a = np.random.randn(3,3)
b = np.empty((3,3))
c = np.empty((3,3))
print(a, id(a)) # id gives memory address of array
print(b, id(b))
print(c, id(c))
```

with output:

```
[[ 0.25754195  1.13184341 -0.46048928]
 [-0.80635852  0.92340661  2.08962923]
 [ 0.09552521  0.14940356  0.5644782 ]] 139865678073408
[[-1.63665076 -0.41916461  0.9251386 ]
 [ 2.72595838  0.10575355 -0.03555088]
 [ 0.71242678  0.09749262  0.24742165]] 139865678071568
[[-0.41824453  0.66565604  1.52995102]
 [ 0.8365397   0.32796832 -0.07150151]
 [-0.08558753  0.96326938 -0.56601338]] 139865678072688
```

versus

```
# Run this 2 or more times and b and c will always be the same!

a = np.random.randn(3,3)
b = np.empty((3,3))
c = np.empty((3,3))
>>> a, id(a) # output without using print

(array([[-0.04230878,  0.18081425,  0.36880091],
    [ 0.4426956 , -1.31697583,  1.53143212],
    [ 0.58197615,  0.42028897,  0.27644022]]), 139865678070528)

>>> b, id(b)

(array([[-0.41824453,  0.66565604,  1.52995102],
    [ 0.8365397 ,  0.32796832, -0.07150151],
    [-0.08558753,  0.96326938, -0.56601338]]), 139865678048912)

>>> c, id(c) # c will have the same values as b!

(array([[-0.41824453,  0.66565604,  1.52995102],
    [ 0.8365397 ,  0.32796832, -0.07150151],
    [-0.08558753,  0.96326938, -0.56601338]]), 139865678069888)
```

Trying running each multiple times in a row to give the memory a chance to fall into a pattern. Also, you'll get different behavior depending on which order you run those two blocks.

Noting the behavior of 'empty' arrays b and c when we print and don't print, I'd guess there is a sort of "lazy evaluation" happening with using output and because the memory remains 'free' (that's why c gets the same value as b in the last example), **Python has no obligation to print exact values for an array that hasn't actually memory-allocated** (malloc'd) yet, i.e. unsigned representations, or really anything is fair game until you 'use'. In my examples, I 'use' the array by printing it, and that may explain why in my first example you see the signs are preserved with printing.

Comment: I'm not seeing the effects you report regarding `print`/just letting `sys.displayhook` handle it in the second and third code snippets. I think you're seeing unrelated effects and attributing them to `print`. Also, there's no laziness involved, and `numpy.matlib.empty` is a completely different function from `numpy.empty`.

Comment: Regarding the first snippet, that looks like it's because the `randn` array isn't being implicitly saved to `_`, so the `empty` call grabs a different buffer than it otherwise would. Testing with `__array_interface__` suggests it's grabbing the `randn` array's buffer.